# Magento Paypal Error #10413 Fee added twice

Tags: magento, paypal

I just upgraded from `Magento 1.6 to 1.9.2.1`. So far everything came over pretty much correctly except that when I'm using `Paypal` I have an extension Magentix Fee that adds a certain amount to the subtotal. When the request is sent to Paypal it's including the grand total AMT(that already includes the fee) plus the amount of the fee `ITEMAMT` (grand total + fee) which brings throws off the calculation. So I getting the error:

> "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts
>   (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument.)"

Anyone can help?

Comment: can you log the complete response(including correlation id) and post it here?

Comment: [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-09-22T14:46:32Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 201feb381e2d3
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 000000
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The 10413 error is thrown when the totals do not match.

PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT must exactly equal:

PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT +
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPPINGAMT +
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INSURANCEAMT -
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPDISCAMT +
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_HANDLINGAMT +
PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT

If those do not add up to the AMT field, the error will be thrown.

This error commonly occurs if your cart does any sort of rounding. Check to make sure that the amounts for the items/shipping are not passing with more than 2 decimal places and that the amounts add up correctly.

Comment: The problem is that AMT is less than ITEMAMT.  The  ITEMAMT is AMT plus the fee amount that's already calculated into AMT

Comment: Please provide an example with the amounts you are passing for these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I added an item to the Paypal cart through an observer.  Magentix Fee extension was adding it to the total instead of as an item that paypal need to do proper calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Magentix is only compatible with Magento 1.7 and below.

For magento 1.9, either you disable "transfer cart line items" option in Magento admin Paypal payment method or modify the function updatePaypalTotal() function in Magentix observer class to replace $cart->updateTotal() with $cart->addItem("Fee", 1, $fee, "fee").